# Pyspark: conditionally concatenate columns with whitespace

Tags: python, pyspark

Given I have the following table:

```
ColA     |   ColB   |  ColC  |  ColD

Name         BA         CC       DA      
Name         BB         CC       DA
```

I want to check whether values of ColB, ColC and ColD are same for all of the rows(name is always same). If they are, I need to return my df as it is. If they are not, I should append those that differ to my ColA.

So in this scenario, where we have inconsistent column B, my resulting table should look like this:

```
ColA       |   ColB   |  ColC  |  ColD

Name BA        BA         CC       DA      
Name BB        BB         CC       DA
```

I've had some troubles but I came out with this function. However, the problem is that I cannot make it work with whitespace. So currently my result looks like that:

```
ColA       |   ColB   |  ColC  |  ColD

NameBA        BA         CC       DA      
NameBB        BB         CC       DA
```

Function:

```
def id(df, cols):
  """
  """
  def is_not_unique_col(df, x):
    """
    """
    if len(df.select(x).distinct().collect()) != 1:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def concat_with_whitespace(*cols):
    """
    """
    return F.concat(*[F.coalesce(c, F.lit(" ")) for c in cols])

  non_unique_cols = [x for x in cols if is_not_unique_col(df, x)]
  if len(non_unique_cols)>0:
    df = df.withColumn("ColA_New", concat_with_whitespace("ColA", *non_unique_cols)).drop("ColA")
    df = df.withColumnRenamed("ColA_New", "ColA").drop("ColA_New")
    return df
  else:
    return df
```

I've got this `is_not_unique_col` function, which checks whether a column has multiple values or not. I run it for all my columns and those that return True are appended to the non_unique_cols list, which is used as an input for my `concat_with_whitespace` function. I have added this `F.lit(" ")` within, in order to get my whitespace. Everything seems to be correct but I cannot make it work. I would appreciate if someone could take  aloook, maybe that's some stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a solution without using any UDFs.

Use `collect_set()` to get the list of column names with non-unique values

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

diff_col = [i for i in df.schema.names if \
    (df.select(F.size(F.collect_set(i))).collect()[0][0] > 1)]
```

For concactenating:

```
df.select(col("*"), concat(col("ColA"), lit(" "),concat(*diff_col))\
        .alias("concat_col")).show()

+----+----+----+----+----------+
|ColA|ColB|ColC|ColD|concat_col|
+----+----+----+----+----------+
|Name|  BA|  CC|  DA|   Name BA|
|Name|  BB|  CC|  DA|   Name BB|
+----+----+----+----+----------+
```

Or if you want spaces between concats of multiple columns (in case you have multiple columns of non-unique values), then:

```
df.select(col("*"), concat(col("ColA"), lit(" "),\
    concat(*[F.concat(col(i),F.lit(" "))for i in diff_col])).alias("concat_col")).show()
```